# Nautilus icons are not displayed

Tags: 11.10, nautilus

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and sometimes Nautilus icons stop being displayed and it looks like this:

[image: broken stuff]

Is there a way to fix this without rebooting?

Comment: It seems that something crashes. You can know what has crashed looking at the oputpu of `dmesg | tail` and then launch that program again.

Comment: As I can see in the image, this situation may be caused because Nautilus can't access both /usr/share/themes and /usr/share/icons (probably it can't access any superuser directory). I don't know why it might caused, but I think that this is the problem.

Comment: @dadexix86, I couldn't find anything related there - perhaps because it happened a while ago and was overwritten

Comment: @Alfredo Hernández, but it works properly after I restart the PC - how could this be permission related?

Comment: Is this only happening to Nautilus, or with any GTK+ application?

Comment: Well, I'm not quite sure. Icons are disappearing in nautilus only, but there are some other issues like invisible menus in Clementine http://code.google.com/p/clementine-player/issues/detail?id=2301

Comment: @Fluffy: you should look in there just after it crashes. Anyway just `dmesg` reports all the messages in the current session.

Comment: Looks like `gnome-settings-daemon` has crashed

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem (Ubuntu 11.10 oneiric).

I installed GNOME Tweak Tool:

> sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool

It showed up as "Advanced Settings" in the menu (Dash home). I ran the tool and I started playing with some options, most likely the one that did the trick was: Theme-> Buttons Have Icons.

Hope this helps.

Juan